# Stop scrolling when an image increases height

Tags: html, slideshow

I have a slideshow with images with diferent sizes but I have a problem, when a bigger image appears the page scrolls down a little. Is there any possible way to stop the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.
Just use the following style.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I don't want to downvote your answer but that just makes it impossible to navigate in my website, I just wanted it to not move when an image switches